# Error while creating javascript object property

Tags: javascript, object, associative

I'm trying to create a javascript associative object, every thing works fine, but
variable passed to create property name is not working, instead of storing variable value its converting variable into string and show variable name itself.

Quick Sample Below

```
var users = {};
var genID = someId;

createObj('userID', function(userID, username, email) {
users[userID] = { genID: { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d } };
})
```

Expected result;

```
users = { 1: { 11: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 } } }
```

Getting result;

```
users = { 1: { genID: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 } } }​
```

Please help me to resolve these. Thank You..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what you did. The first thing worked: `users[userID]`. However, the second one `genID` didn't. That's because when you're using object notation, it assumes you're typing in the 'name' not a variable, so it doesn't resolve that. better would be:

```
var obj = {};
obj[genID] = {a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d};
users[userID] = obj;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasted my time debugging these and searching for ans over internet, Finally your answer resolved the issue. Thank you..

Comment: Small question, is there something like size limit for javascript associative object storage?

Comment: :) If there is, i've not hit it yet, and I've made some pretty big objects at times. Don't worry, cross that bridge once you get there. This way you'll just waste time browsing for information you might never need. Just finish the project :)

Answer (score 2):

You need square bracket syntax:

```
users[userID] = {};
users[userID][genID] = { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d };
```

Basically `genID` must be used where expression is expected (inside square brackets). You are using it on the left side when object literal is expected. `genID` is treated there as a constant identifier and it is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
users[userID] = {};
users[userID][genID] = { { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d } };
```